# merging two xmls of same number of nodes

Tags: java, xml, merge

I have merged two xml files using java dom parser:
a.xml

```
<config>
<category name="mimetypes">
<!-- application mime types -->
<mime-type type=1></mime-type>
<!-- eps -->
<mime-type type=2></mime-type>
<!-- octet-stream -->
<mime-type type=3></mime-type>
</category>
</config>
```

b.xml:

```
<config>
<category name="mimetypes">
<!-- application mime types -->
<!-- eps -->
<mime-type type=2></mime-type>
<!-- octet-stream -->
<mime-type type=3></mime-type>
<mime-type type=4></mime-type>
</category>
</config>
```

the output I get

```
<config>
<category name="mimetypes">
<!-- application mime types -->
<mime-type type=1></mime-type>
<!-- eps -->
<mime-type type=2></mime-type>
<!-- octet-stream -->
<mime-type type=3></mime-type>
</category>
<mime-type type=2></mime-type>
</config>
```

Expected:

```
<config>
<category name="mimetypes">
<!-- application mime types -->
<mime-type type=1></mime-type>
<!-- eps -->
<mime-type type=2></mime-type>
<!-- octet-stream -->
<mime-type type=3></mime-type>
<mime-type type=4></mime-type>
</category>
</config>
```

Code I have tried:

```
public class MergeXmlDemo {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder db = null;
        Document doc = null;
        Document doc2 = null;
                db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
                doc = db.parse(new File("second.xml"));
                doc2 = db.parse(new File("first.xml"));
                NodeList ndListFirstFile = doc.getElementsByTagName("config");
                Node nodeArea = doc.importNode(doc2.getElementsByTagName("mime-type").item(0), true);
                ndListFirstFile.item(0).appendChild(nodeArea);
                TransformerFactory tFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
                Transformer transformer = tFactory.newTransformer();
                transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");  
                DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
                //StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new StringWriter());
                StreamResult result = new StreamResult(System.out);
                transformer.transform(source, result); 
}
```

merging two xml files with same number of nodes is giving the file with same number of nodes and type=4 is missing from the output.
Any help is appreciated

Comment: The attribute order in XML elements doesn't matter. `<node a=".." b=".."/>` and `<node b=".." a=".." />` are essentially the same. Only two possible string representations for exactly the same element.

Comment: But while merging since the two input files have three nodes,the</category> after third node and the last node doesn't print,instead the first node is repeating @vanje

Comment: Please show the XML you get, then it will be more clear. And show us your code, too. Without it is impossible to find the problem.

Comment: i have updated the output I get@vanje

Comment: Hm, your code takes the first mime-type element of the second document and adds it to the first's document config node. Why do you do that? Shouldn't there some kind of loop? If I understand you correctly, you want in your result doc all first document's  mime-type elements and then only those second doc's mime-type element with a type not present in the first doc. Is that right? Then you should traverse each second doc's mime-type element, check whether the type value is present in the first doc and ...

Comment: ... add it to first document's category element, if the check was negative. This approach could work. Now all you have to do is write the appropriate code.

Comment: ok.Thank you@vanje